# verilog sync issue with counter

Tags: verilog

i'm trying to create a 8 bit parallel to serial component that send the data and bit number.
the bit number and the transmitted serial data is not sent at the right time, 
please see wave form

```
module counter
(
input clk,rst,
input [7:0]data,
output reg [7:0]cnt,
output reg data_Tx
);

parameter lim = 7;


always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
if (!rst)
begin
    cnt <= 0;
    data_Tx <= 1'b1;
end

else
begin
    if (clk)
    begin
    if (cnt < lim)
    begin
        data_Tx <= data[cnt];
        cnt <= cnt +1;
    end
    else
        cnt <= 0;
    end
end

endmodule
```

[please see wave form here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsiDn.png)

i have marked on the waveform (in blue) the bit numbers that supposed to be transmitted, as you can see they are shifted.

also, in red circle, the data_Tx needs to be '0' when transmitting the first bit from the parallel inputs, but i'ts '1'because of the rst line, how can i fix this situation?

should i use a state machine???

thank you

Comment: Your synchronous logic updates on posedge clk, so data_Tx is expected to be 1 before that (unless you change the reset value). Also, remove `if (clk)`, otherwise a synthesizer will think it is an async control signal instead of a clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have fallen into the standard trap all beginners with HDL have: your signals change *after* the clock edge. Take a few months of coding and dealing with this becomes second nature.

But before I deal with that: follow Greg's advice and remove the `if (clk)` from the code.

The first, simple solution, is to move the `data_Tx <= data[cnt];` outside the clocked section:

```
assign data_Tx = data[cnt];
```

But beware that makes that after a reset (when cnt is zero) the `data_Tx` bit reflects your `data[0]` bit. So there is no guarantee that it is 1. Also it will change as soon as a new value is assigned to `data`.

If you want a synchronous `data_Tx` output and want the `cnt` to be inline you have to delay your `cnt` by a clock cycle:

```
....
reg [2:0] early_cnt;
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
if (!rst)
begin
    cnt <= 0;
    early_cnt <= 8'h00;
    data_Tx <= 1'b1;
end
else
begin
    cnt  <= early_cnt;
    if (early_cnt < lim)
    begin
        data_Tx <= data[early_cnt];
        early_cnt <= early_cnt + 8'h01;
    end
    else
        early_cnt <= 0;
end
```